# What is the difference between f_inode of the file object and d_inode of the dentry object in the Linux VFS?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, inode, vfs

I understand that when a file is opened, its inode is brought into memory.

I want to know whether the f_inode in the file object and the d_inode in the dentry object both point to the same in-memory inode for a given file.

Answer (score 1):

The key difference (as the characters d and f implies) is that f_inode points to the inode associated with a file, while d_inode points to the inode associated with a directory.

```
struct file *my_file;
struct dentry *my_dentry;  

struct inode *file_inode = my_file->f_inode;
struct inode *dir_inode = my_dentry->d_inode;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have another question related to the scenario you explained. Assuming there is a 'test' file under the 'dir' directory, and the inode number for the 'dir' directory on disk is 123, while the inode number for the 'test' file on disk is 456. If there is a directory entry <test, 456> in the 'dir' directory, and I use the open system call to open 'test', my understanding is that the f_inode in the file object created by VFS for 'test' would be 456, and the d_inode in the dentry object pointed to by the file would be 123. Could you please confirm this for me?

Comment: `dentry object pointed to by the file` Can you provide some code to explain this? A file can be in multiple directories.

Comment: Sorry for the imprecise wording. What I meant was the `'dentry' object pointed to by the 'file' object`. By that, I refer to the 'dentry' object that is being pointed to by the file object created for the 'test' file. You can see in the 'file' object there is an 'f_path', and each 'f_path' corresponds to a 'dentry' object.